# How to start the application optimization process without having to restart the device?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, system-apps

**Hello everyone**

I have a question, I had to install an application manually, moving its data, dex and apk to the corresponding directories in the / data, but for the moment the application did not appear installed, but when restarting the device, and on power up I showed a message saying : **Updating the system, optimizing app**, when finished everything perfect the installed application and everything, but now I have left with a doubt that is: **How can I start the optimization of the application without having to reboot the device**, with some command or something so.